# PHP: Incorporar valor a un array

Tags: php, array

Tengo las siguientes estructuras de datos:

```
var_dump($json);

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'idLista' => string '26' (length=2)
      'rutaFoto' => string 'http://localhost/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc//recursos/imagenes/varias/favicon2.png' (length=82)
      'nombreLista' => string 'Aquellos maravillosos 90' (length=24)
      'nombreUsuario' => string 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW' (length=25)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'idLista' => string '25' (length=2)
      'rutaFoto' => string 'http://localhost/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc//recursos/imagenes/varias/favicon2.png' (length=82)
      'nombreLista' => string 'Instrumentales' (length=14)
      'nombreUsuario' => string 'Javi' (length=4)

var_dump($puestos);

array (size=8)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '27' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '30' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[8]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '32' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[9]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '25' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '28' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '5' (length=1)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '26' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '6' (length=1)
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[12]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '31' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '7' (length=1)
  7 => 
    object(stdClass)[13]
      public 'id_lista_youtube' => string '29' (length=2)
      public 'puesto' => string '8' (length=1)
```

Y quiero que si `idLista` de `$json` e `id_lista_youtube` de `$puestos` coinciden, se añada `puesto` a `$json` (es decir, el 4 para el 25 y el 6 para el 26):

```
foreach($json as $clave => $fila)
{
    foreach($puestos as $clave2 => $fila2)
    {
        if($fila['idLista'] == $fila2->id_lista_youtube) $fila['puesto'] = $fila2->puesto;
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, si a continuación hago otro `var_dump($json);` se comprueba que no se ha añadido nada:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'idLista' => string '26' (length=2)
      'rutaFoto' => string 'http://localhost/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc//recursos/imagenes/varias/favicon2.png' (length=82)
      'nombreLista' => string 'Aquellos maravillosos 90' (length=24)
      'nombreUsuario' => string 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW' (length=25)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'idLista' => string '25' (length=2)
      'rutaFoto' => string 'http://localhost/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc//recursos/imagenes/varias/favicon2.png' (length=82)
      'nombreLista' => string 'Instrumentales' (length=14)
      'nombreUsuario' => string 'Javi' (length=4)
```

Creo que se me está pasando por alto alguna tontería, pero no soy capaz de ver el qué.

Comment: Prueba con `foreach($json as $clave => &$fila)`

Comment: Eso era, el pase por referencia. Algo que nunca he entendido de qué va, la verdad, y que es la primera vez que tengo que usar.

Comment: Podes poner la cadena del json para experimentar?

Comment: El array se llama `$json` porque en última instancia se codifica en un json para que un script jQuery lo maneje, pero en este punto su estructura es la que se muestra en el `var_dump($json);`.